# Why won't my random walk work in a Mathematica Do loop?

Tags: random, procedural-programming

This produces a nice random walk plot:

```
randomWalk[n_] := Module[{steps, walk},   
   steps = 2 RandomInteger[{0, 1}, n] - 1;
   walk = Accumulate[steps];
   ListLinePlot[walk, ImageSize -> 200]]

randomWalk[200]
```

[image: random walk]

But if I put it in a `Do` loop, nothing appears.

```
Do[randomWalk[200], 4]
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, try [avoiding procedural loops in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/27951). A better approach here could be `Table[randomwalk[200], 4]`. This will return its results in a list, whereas `Do` (or `For`, or `While`) do not return anything at all.

Comment: Thank you. That gave me a result but no graphics -
{randomwalk[200], randomwalk[200], randomwalk[200], randomwalk[200]}
Is there a way to generate graphics as in the single case? You're right about Do, though. I've had a lot of trouble with it - something to avoid since it's not ready for prime time 

Comment: Typo - it should have been `Table[randomWalk[200], 4]` (note the uppercase W in the function name).

Answer (score 5):

Because the `Do` does not return value. i.e what is generated inside the `Do` does not show up on the screen. You either need an explicit `Print` from inside the `Do` to see the output, or use `Sow`/`Reap` to collect the output. (or can also use a list and append to it, but Sow/Reap is supposed to be more efficient).

```
  Last@Reap@Do[Sow@randomWalk[200], 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See this for reference

[What has changed in Mathematica since version 2 so that Do no longer can be used to make animations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173987/what-has-changed-in-mathematica-since-version-2-so-that-do-no-longer-can-be-used)

> There was a major overhaul of graphics in 2007 for V6, one aspect of
> which was that Mathematica switched from displaying graphics as a
> side-effect, to rendering directly in the notebook.
>
> Since graphics are no longer a side effect, Do doesn't display the
> individual plots anymore.

Comment: Why using `Reap`+`Do`+`Sow` when a simple `Table` can be used?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Table can also be used ofcourse. I was just using the OP code, that is all. In Mathematica, there are at least 10 different ways to do the same thing, and one can not think of every one all the time.